# Using a Linux Socket to Connect to the JavaScript Console

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, console

I'm trying to programmatically connect to a JavaScript console (just like you get with `geth attach`) using the geth.ipc file that gets created in the chaindata folder.  On Linux, it's a socket file, so I figured I could connect to it with something like this (in Python):

```
import socket

client = socket.socket( socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
client.connect("/home/john/Desktop/EthPrivateChain/chaindata/geth.ipc")

client.send(str.encode("admin.nodeInfo.enode"))
print(str(client.recv(1024)))

client.close()
```

However, this gives me the JSON RPC, not the JavaScript console.  The code works but the endpoint returns an error when I try this.  The same code, but with a JSON request, works.  I want the JavaScript console because I want to be able to access some stuff that isn't available through the JSON RPC, specifically the enode in this case.  I think there has to be a way to connect to that file this way because I can use it to start a console with `geth attach /home/john/Desktop/EthPrivateChain/chaindata/geth.ipc`.  Is there some way I can make this socket file access the JavaScript API when I access it with my own code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `geth attach` only creates its own javascript read-eval-loop, but still uses JSON-RPC commands to talk with geth node through the ipc file.

Geth provides a sets of more advanced commands that are only accessible using JSON-RPC that are `geth` only [Management APIs](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs).

Some of this APIs can be accessed from javascript with [web3Admin](https://github.com/DecentricCorp/web3admin).

Comment: For anyone else trying to do this, the management API documentation says that you need to explicitly enable these APIs in the command line when you start Geth, but I didn't have to.  They were enabled by default in Geth 1.7.3.

Comment: @JohnStanford They are enabled by default if you use IPC, but you need to explicitely enable them if you use the RPC interface.